# getting parquet from maven repo

Tags: maven, parquet

I am trying to get the latest version of parquet from maven (1.6.0rc7). I think I finally have maven & the project folder set up correctly. I added the dependency to the project, etc., but it looks like maven is looking for a jar, and there is only a pom:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twitter/parquet/1.6.0rc7/parquet-1.6.0rc7.jar

Failed to execute goal on project parquet: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter:parquet:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.twitter:parquet:jar:1.6.0rc7 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I looked through some posts, and it looks like there might be a problem when there is a jar & no pom and vice versa, but I don't understand maven well enough to figure out if this is really the problem or if something else is going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I could just give up and install the previous version, which comes in a nice little standalone jar, but I really want to figure this out!!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it all working (I think!)

I'll post the detailed steps here in case anyone else needs help getting maven working to get parquet... and then getting parquet itself.

This is all for the mac OS.

Set up maven:
download apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.tar.gz from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and put into Documents folder

execute following commands in terminal

```
gunzip ~/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.tar.gz
cd /usr/local
sudo tar xvf ~/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.tar
```

edit .bash_profile & add the following:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile

export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

move to where you want to house your parquet files & execute the following

```
cd /usr/local
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.twitter -DartifactId=parquet -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
cd parquet
```

make your pom.xml look like this (update the version numbers!)

```
vi pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
  <artifactId>parquet</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.6.0rc7</version>
  <name>parquet</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
      <artifactId>parquet</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0rc7</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

execute the next two commands to install & compile parquet

```
mvn clean install -U
mvn compile
```